# C++: No output on eclipse console

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, console, building

Hello and thanks in advance for helping,
I've the problem that I don't see any output on my eclipse console (on linux ubuntu 12.04).
I have this little C++ program:

Addressverwaltung.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Adresse.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "asdf";
    Adresse lAdresse1("Max", "Tester", "Strasse 21", 6423, "lol", "asdf@hotmail.com");
    lAdresse1.printAdresse();
    lAdresse1.setName("Testing");
    lAdresse1.printAdresse();

    return 0;
}
```

Adresse.h:

```
#ifndef Adresse_h
#define Adresse_h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Adresse{
    public:
        Adresse(std::string pVorname, std::string pName);
        Adresse(std::string pVorname, std::string pName, std::string pStrasse, int pPlz, std::string pOrt, std::string pEmail);
        void printAdresse();
        void setVorname(std::string pVorname);
        void setName(std::string pName);
        std::string getName();
    private:
        std::string mVorname;
        std::string mName;
        std::string mStrasse;
        int mPlz;
        std::string mOrt;
        std::string mEmail;



};


#endif
```

Adresse.cpp:

```
#include "Adresse.h"

Adresse::Adresse(std::string pVorname, std::string pName){
    mVorname = pVorname;
    mName = pName;
}

Adresse::Adresse(std::string pVorname, std::string pName, std::string pStrasse, int pPlz, std::string pOrt, std::string pEmail){
    mVorname = pVorname;
    mName = pName;
    mStrasse = pStrasse;
    mPlz = pPlz;
    mOrt = pOrt;
    mEmail = pEmail;
}

void Adresse::printAdresse(){
    std::cout << "ADRESSE:";
    std::cout << mVorname + mName;
    std::cout << "STRASSE: " + mStrasse;
    std::cout << "PLZ: " + mPlz;
    std::cout << "EMAIL: " + mEmail;
}

void Adresse::setVorname(std::string pVorname){
    mVorname = pVorname;
}

void Adresse::setName(std::string pName){
    mName = pName;
}

std::string Adresse::getName(){
    return mName;
}
```

Whenever I click "run" I see the message "make all 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'." for about 4 seconds, afterwards the console is empty. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but that doesn't help. 
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you choose 'Debug' instead of 'Run'?

Comment: you can go through code of course, but theres still no output, and at cout << mPlz (in the method printadresse) it suddenly stops and says "Can't find a source file at "../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-sse2-pminub.S" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location."
what I found out: When I put a << endl; on all outputs in printAdresse();, at least the name and strasse get on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a cout.flush() before the return in main() function. That should help:

```
int main() {
    cout << "asdf";
    Adresse lAdresse1("Max", "Tester", "Strasse 21", 6423, "lol", "asdf@hotmail.com");
    lAdresse1.printAdresse();
    lAdresse1.setName("Testing");
    lAdresse1.printAdresse();

    cout.flush(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't show me mPlz (6423) on the console as well as the email, is this because mPlz is an integer?

Comment: @RandomDisplayName _'because mPlz is an integer'_ Yes. You can't concatenate string (literal) and integer, use `<<` instead of `+`!